# iPhone APNS Sandbox vs. Production for not yet approved apps

Tags: iphone, sandbox, apple-push-notifications

Is it true that the production APNS is unavailable until an app is approved to the app store?  I can use the sandbox certificates fine, but production yields no results.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the production push services if you build your app with a distribution provisioning profile (as with an ad hoc build). You'll get a different device token, and the app will connect with Apple's production push service.